# Kotlin & Android Studio: allow use of all ssl certificates

Tags: android, kotlin, https, ssl-certificate

My Android App should perfom some SET and GET requests. When I´m doing it with 'http' everything works fine, but as soon as I use 'https' I get:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

I know that this happens because the https URL i want to use is a private one without an 'accepted' certificate.
And I don´t have any file of this certificate.

So my question is: How can I allow my android application to accept all ssl certificates?

Comment: It can be done, of course, but it's a bad idea. Instead, configure it to accept the specific certificate for the specific website. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/59930234/238704

Comment: "How can I allow my android application to accept all ssl certificates?" -- bear in mind that your app may be banned from the Play Store and perhaps other app distribution channels if you try this.

Comment: @CommonsWare The app is ony for private use.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Like I said I don't have a .pem or any other file. So I think allowing all certificates would be the only way.

Comment: If you have an URL you can download the server certificate yourself and integrate it into the NetworkSecurityConfig so your app will accept it.

Comment: @Robert Sometimes things are just much easier than you think, haha. I successfully downloaded the certificate. But Android Studio says that it can not use this file-type (pem and crt). Any ideas what I can do?

Comment: AS doesn't work with certificates because you can not edit certificates and you simply have to reference it at the correct point. Just build your own NetworSecurityConfig.xml file and add it as custom root CA https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config

Comment: @Robert Thank you! But now I got another problem: When trying to start the app I get this error: 'SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname (url of the website) not verified.' I figured out that it probably has something to do with the fact that I am using a REST-api.
Do you know what I can do to fix this?

Comment: For HTTPS is is totally irrelevant if the used API is REST or not. The TLS tunnel will be established long before the request is sent. Why you get an SSLPeerUnverifiedException is unknown to me, may be the certificate was generated in a wrong way (contains the wrong data) or something else. Please update your question with the code that generates the request and the server certificate + certificate chain and how you have built the cert.